# Tuple with Int member not recognized where Long is required

Tags: scala

I've got a function that expects a Tuple2, where one item must be a long. When I attempt to pass pairs with literal numbers using the `->` implicit, they are being interpreted as `Int` instead of `Long`.

Here, the problem is demonstrated:

```
scala> val x: (Long, String) = (5, "test") 
x: (Long, String) = (5,test)

scala> val x: (Long, String) = 5L -> "test"
x: (Long, String) = (5,test)

scala> val x: (Long, String) = 5 -> "test"
<console>:43: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, String)
 required: (Long, String)
       val x: (Long, String) = 5 -> "test"
```

I suppose the problem is that when the implicit is applied, type inference locks in on `Int`, but in the first example, type inference is nice enough to consider the number a `Long`.

But my DSL works much better if I can use `->` and omit the `L` suffix. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Int` is not formally a subtype of `Long`. Thus, an `(Int, String)` can not be passed where a `(Long, String)` is expected, despite the fact that `Tuple2` is covariant in its type parameters.

However, `Int` is *viewable* as `Long`. So, you can design a function that will upconvert an `Int` to a `Long` the following way:

```
scala> def goodFunc[LongLike <% Long](arg: (LongLike, String)) = { "whatevs" }
goodFunc: [LongLike](arg: (LongLike, String))(implicit evidence$1: LongLike => Long)String

scala> goodFunc(5 -> "test")
res4: String = whatevs
```

Or, better yet, use:

```
def goodFunc[LongLike](arg: (LongLike, String))(implicit ev: LongLike => Long) = { "whatevs" }
```

, since `<%` is deprecated.

Comment: You need something like `def goodFunc[LongLike](arg: (LongLike, String))(implicit ev: LongLike => Long) = { "whatevs" }`. Notice `LongLike` instead of `Long` in the parameter list.

Comment: @Jasper-M Aaargh, haha, yeah. I knew I had missed something.